# How to add empty arraylist to a ListView? Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, arraylist

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    NoteTaking_Activity noteTaking_activity = new NoteTaking_Activity();

    arrayList = noteTaking_activity.getHeadlineArray();

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List_Of_notes);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList );

    listView.setAdapter( adapter );
```

Executing the code shown above results in the error message

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference.
```

The array list is empty at first, but then users may fill it.

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you show us your `getHeadlineArray()` function? I bet that's returning `null` instead of an ArrayList.

Comment: getHeadlineArray() is simply a getter for my an arraylist (the headline array)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        NoteTaking_Activity noteTaking_activity = new NoteTaking_Activity();

        arrayList = noteTaking_activity.getHeadlineArray();

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List_Of_notes);
if(arrayList!=null){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList );

        listView.setAdapter( adapter );
}
```

Comment: Would work if OP was using a custom adapter, but a default [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) is being used in this case.

Comment: if its' default adapter then you can add `arrayList!=null` and show the error message `No data found`.

Comment: when I do that, the app will no more crash, but it won't carry out reading other statements in the onCreate method.

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it.

Comment: @Hossein If it resolves your issue can you please accept the answer...